# MySQL UPDATE and SELECT from same table in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

First off, I know this is impossible as of MySQL 5.1.x, it says so right here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html

What I'm asking though is if there is a clever way to execute a query using either a temporarily table/view without having to resort to writing a quick script to do the work. My query (which is COMPLETELY WRONG and DOES NOT work, just an FYI for folks trying this at home) looks something like this:

```
UPDATE some_table 
set some_col = ( SELECT some_othercol 
                 from some_table 
                 WHERE some_col > some_othercol
               );
```

I'm trying to ultimately set `some_col` to the value of `some_othercol` if `sol_col > some_othercol`.

What's the best way to handle this without resorting to a script?

*EDIT*
My subquery returns more than one row!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? That query is trying to set each row's some_col value to a set of values. Logically, what do you want the end result to be?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand why you need a subquery. Doesn't this do what you want?:

```
UPDATE some_table 
SET some_col = some_othercol 
WHERE some_col > some_othercol
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you're trying to do, but maybe I can show you something to put you on the right path.

```
UPDATE some_table ST
SET some_col = (
    SELECT some_col
    FROM some_table OT
    WHERE OT.ID = ST.ID
)
WHERE ST.some_col > 2
```

That will set some_col to its own value, but only when some_col is already greater than 2. I know this doesn't do anything, but it shows a concept that may be closer to what you're looking for. If you give some more detail as to what you what to happen in the end, I can possibly help you find a solution closer to what you need.

Comment: I think this will also throw an error in MySQL because sub-select using the same table as the one that is being updated

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/ is the best resource I know on that subject.

Comment: sorry I should have added an important bit which I don't think the URL above addresses, my subquery returns multiple rows

Comment: does that even make sense conceptually? how could you set a single field's value to something involving multiple rows?  the subquery is specific to the row being updated... if you have multiple update rows you'll need to write the query so that the subquery is executed for each one I believe.